# Laravel: Eloquent / Tinker Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get data in a relationship with tinker. I get an error that says Class 'App\Date' not found. I think cause I am not using the right code, but I have no idea what code I need.

I have 2 models:

Contact (app\Models\Contact.php) 
Date (app\Models\Date.php)

**Contact**

```
public function dates(){
   return $this->hasMany(Date::class);
}
```

**Tinker**

```
php artisan tinker

$test = App\Models\Contact::find(516);
```

$test returns a user.
If I uses $test->dates after that I get an error saying this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]Class 'App\Date' not found
```

Comment: Show your Contact model, please. Mostly the relationship part.

Comment: The relationship part has been shown already, its the public function dates()

Comment: Use `return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Date, 'contact_id');`

Comment: Try the full namespace in your relationship. `App\Models\Date::class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$test->dates` is most likely a relationship. In that relation, it's failing to find the class used in the relationship.

```
public function dates(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Date');
}
```

Comment: I think I need to tell the relationship that the Date class is in app\Models\ ? Is that possible?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? If models are within the same namespace, your code should actually work.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: I've restarded php storm and my ssd, it works for some reason now with your code. Think it had something to do with old code or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're using correct namespace in the `Date.php`, it should be `namespace App\Models;` and not `namespace App;`

Comment: I'm using App\Models; as namespace in my Date.php, still won't work

Comment: @KoenvandeSande make sure you're using correct namespace in `Contact` class too and try to run `composer dumpauto` command